# Deploying NodeJS service with Cloud Run - Dockerfile problem

Tags: node.js, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I have a NodeJS service located on serviceA. In this folder I have a Dockerfile I created and the entry point for this service which is a file called app.js.

On the app.js file I have this:

```
var auth = require('../common/authentication/authentication.js');
```

When I try to deploy, I do this from serviceA folder:

> docker build -t serviceA .
> docker run -p 8080:8080 serviceA

But then I get:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../common/authentication/authentication.js'
Require stack:
- /usr/src/app/app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/app.js:46:12)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/src/app/app.js' ]
}
```

If I modify my Dockerfile to include:

```
RUN cp -R ../common /usr/src
```

Then I get this when running docker build:

```
 > [2/7] RUN cp -R ../common /usr/src:
#4 0.327 cp: cannot stat '../common': No such file or directory
```

This is my current Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official lightweight Node.js 12 image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/node
FROM node:17-slim

RUN cp -R ../common /usr/src

# Create and change to the app directory.
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
# Copy application dependency manifests to the container image.
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied.
# Copying this separately prevents re-running npm install on every code change.
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies.
# If you add a package-lock.json speed your build by switching to 'npm ci'.
# RUN npm ci --only=production
RUN npm install --production
 
# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 
# Run the web service on container startup.
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

I'm not familiar with Dockerfiles but I believe the problem here is that in my container the common folder is not present and I couldn't find a way to include that.

How can I deploy serviceA which makes a reference to ../common folder?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a git repo so that we could replicate the error?

Answer (score 1):

When building, docker sends off a copy of your local directory. If your Dockerfile is at the level of `app.js`, then it is clear that `..` is not part of the Docker context. You can try to move the Dockerfile one level up. That should then send the common directory along (and the copy should work then).

Christian